# Model data not returning null when empty

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

So I'm querying my database and for a return I have two different possibilties, one for if the model set is empty and one for if it has information. However when I run it with an empty table, I still get the response that thinks it has data.

Query works and all, but I just get the same response everytime either success with calls = [] or success with calls having data.

```
IEnumerable<Details> detail = db.Details Where(blah blah blah).ToList().Select(a => new Details { blah blah blah });

var ResponseTrue = new DetailResponse() { status = true, statusMessage = "Success", calls = detail };
var ResponseFalse = new DetailResponse() { status = false, statusMessage = "Set is Empty", calls = detail };

if (detail != null)
{
    return Ok(ResponseTrue);
}

return Ok(ResponseFalse);
```

Comment: What is responseFalse?

Comment: Oh my bad, let me edit it, the second one is supposed to be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Any()

```
if (!detail.Any())
{
    //your code goes here
}
```

Comment: First time it didn't work but that purely user error. I'll have to read more into `.Any()` thank you.